# Fetching json file on offline

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, require

I have this json file which im trying to get hold of its data.

Using, `var data = require('../file.json');` I could get the data, objectified pretty easily,

However - the web browser doesn't support `require.js`, therefore I can't use it.

I saw that `fetch.js` provides the same functionality that I need ( I just want the data in the json file as an object), but I can't use it if it's not hosted online and I do not know how to set a local host server.

Could one provide a solution for such problem? is there another way to "objectifty" the data from the json file like I want to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `res.json()` to get json format of data.

```
fetch("../file.json")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
``
```